# Image disappears when hovering then appears - CSS

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image on my webpage which is this image

[image]

When I hover over the image it is suppose to turn to this,

[image]

It does this but when I hover it disappears then the second image appears after about 2 seconds. How can I get this to appear right away? Is it because my internet may be slow?

This is my css,

```
#right_slide_arrow{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:140px;
    background:url(../images/right_arrow.png) no-repeat;
}
#right_slide_arrow:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
    background:url(../images/right_arrow_hover.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image isn't loaded until it is used; at best, this will cause it to blink.

It's better to use an [image sprite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_%28computer_graphics%29#Sprites_by_CSS).

Comment: Good answer, maybe elaborate a bit more on image sprites?